# Are guest hosts paid for being on Saturday Night Live (SNL)?

Tags: saturday-night-live

I realize that hosts on SNL are often there to plug whatever project they're working on. But unlike going on a talk show for 15 minutes, it's a much bigger multi-day commitment with practices, learning lines (err..I mean reading cue cards), etc. Other than perhaps lodging/meal/incidental expenses, are they paid for their time?  On a related note, what about the recurring guest spots like Alec Baldwin portraying Donald Trump or Melissa McCarthy playing Sean Spicer?

Comment: Union rules mean that pretty much anyone appearing on screen get paid, even guests on a talk show. The audience doesn't have to be paid, but they can't be charged admission either.

Comment: @RossRidge - I find it interesting that audiences aren't charged for tv shows but are charged for theater shows.

Comment: I think that may be why, if they charged admission to a TV show it would also be theatrical show and they'd have to pay everyone according those union rules as well.

Comment: @RossRidge that would make a really useful answer, actually. The current answers focus on instances of some guest hosts getting paid, while your comment explains that they _have to get paid_, each and everyone of them, in compliance with union rules.

Comment: Having a full, fired-up audience brings great benefits to a talk or entertainment show. The revenue they get from ad revenue makes any audience admission inconsequential.  On a side note, I'm sure if the guest hosts were not required to be paid, most of them would do it for free.  It's a huge, sought-after profile and publicity enhancing honor to host.  Anything that raises the profile and general public appeal of an entertainer translates into a higher price tag for their regular work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Yes:](http://www.vulture.com/2009/05/curious_about_how_much_snl_hos.html)

> Curious About How Much SNL Hosts Get Paid?
>
> So are we! Fortunately, frequent guest-host Justin Timberlake has
>   loose lips. **"It’s the best $5,000 you can make!"**, he told
>   Entertainment Tonight, before adding "If I wouldn’t have been lucky
>   enough to have the profession I have, I probably would have gone
>   through Upright Citizens Brigade and tried to become a cast member on
>   SNL."

[WRT guest spots](http://uk.businessinsider.com/alec-baldwin-donald-trump-snl-salary-1400-2016-12?r=US&IR=T):

> Alec Baldwin revealed that he gets paid just $1,400 for each
>   appearance he makes as President-elect Donald Trump on "Saturday Night
>   Live."

Answer (score 6):

According to an interview Justin Timberlake gave to Entertainment Tonight, yes.

> This was my third time to host and obviously I've done some appearances here and there when I'm in town... I really do adore the cast and the writers and everyone there. I mean it really is... there's no show on television in the world, not just America, that I can think of that is like SNL where you can really throw the kitchen sink, as far as being a performer, at people. And it's... you know... it's a great opportunity for an entertainer like myself to.. it's the best minimum... **It's the best five grand you can make on television.** It's awesome.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturday_Night_Live) lists the base pay for cast members as $5,000 so it would seem guest hosts are paid as cast members.

> By the late 1990s, new cast members received a salary between $5,000 and $5,500.